# Data Pipeline: from AWS RDS Mysql to S3 bucket using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-rds, data-pipeline

I want to build a data pipeline using python.
The current data source is AWS RDS Mysql and DynamoDB.
I want to Fetch daily data as CSV file(i.e. for each date I will fetch incremental data and make one CSV file) and store them into S3 bucket. Rows can be in millions.
Please suggest the efficient way to do this.